# sscanf doesnt seem to capture the correct parts of my strings

Tags: c, string

I've tried to run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char a[1000];
void eliminatesp() {
    char buff1[1000], buff2[1000];
    LOOP: sscanf(a,"%s %s",buff1,buff2);
    sprintf(a,"%s%s", buff1, buff2);
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(a); ++i) {
        if(a[i]==' ') goto LOOP;
    }
}
void eliminateline() {
    char buff1[1000]; char buff2[1000];
    LOOP: sscanf(a,"%s\n\n%s",buff1,buff2);
    sprintf(a,"%s\n%s", buff1, buff2);
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(a)-1; ++i) {
        if(a[i]=='\n'&&a[i+1]=='\n') goto LOOP;
    }
}
int main() {sprintf(a,"%s\n\n%s", "hello world","this is my program, cris"); 
    eliminatesp();
    eliminateline();
    printf("%s",a); return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

but the output was:

```
hello world
world
```

How can I correct it? I was trying to remove spaces and empty lines.

Comment: Don't use `goto` as a replacement of a `while` loop. And if you think that `sscanf` is failing, check the return value of `sscanf` to be sure whether this is a case or not.

Comment: If the `'%s'` *format specifier* stops reading on the first whitespace, how will `if(a[i]==' ')` ever be true?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin aha! thats my mistake... but how can I get sscanf to read past the ' ' char?

Comment: @PedroSecchi I left an answer for you that addresses the `sscanf` challenges. (and don't use `goto` for a loop -- it cannot be optimized as well as other loops can -- save it for jumping out of multiple nested loops)

Comment: Thanks david and @mnistic, i was sort of too inexperient to use sscanf and char pointers with ease. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Going with your idea of using `sscanf` and `sprintf` you can actually eliminate both spaces and newlines in a single function, as `sscanf` [will ignore all whitespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) (including newlines) when reading the input stream. So something like this should work:

```
void eliminate() {
    char buff1[1000], buff2[1000], b[1000];
    char* p = a, *q = b, *pq = b;
    sprintf(q, "%s", p);
    while (q != NULL && *q != '\0')
    {
        if (iswspace(*q))
        {
            sscanf(pq, "%s %s", buff1, buff2);
            sprintf(p, "%s%s", buff1, buff2);
            p += strlen(buff1);
            pq = ++q;
        }
        q++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pedro, while the `%s` format specifier does stop conversion on the first encountered whitespace, it isn't the only drawback to attempting to parse with `sscanf`. In order to use `sscanf` you will also need to use the `%n` conversion specifier (the number of characters consumed during conversion to the point the `%n` appears) and save the value as an integer (say `offset`). Your next conversion will begin a `a + offset` until you have exhausted all words in `'a'`. This can be a tedious process.

A better approach can simply be to loop over all characters in `'a'` copying non-whitespace and single-delimiting whitespace to the new buffer as you go. (I often find it easier to copy the full string to a new buffer (say `'b'`) and then read from `'b'` writing the new compressed string back to `'a'`).

As you work your way down the original string, you use simple `if else` logic to determine whether to store the current (or last) character or whether to just skip it and get the next. There are many ways to do this, no one way more right than the other as long as they are reasonably close in efficiency. Making use of the `<ctype.h>` functions like `isspace()` makes things easier.

Also, in your code, avoid the use of *global variables*. There is no reason you can't declare `'a'` in `main()` and pass it as a parameter to your eliminate functions. If you need a constant in your code, like `1000`, then `#define` a constant and avoid sprinkling *magic numbers* throughout your code.

Below is an example putting all those pieces together, and combining both your `eliminatesp` and `eliminateline` functions into a single `eliminatespline` function that does both trim whitespace and eliminate blank lines. This will handle blank lines and considers lines containing only whitespace characters as blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXL 1000   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

/** trim leading, compress included, and trim trailing whitespace.
 *  given non-empty string 'a', trim all leading whitespace, remove
 *  multiple included spaces and empty lines, and trim all trailing
 *  whitespace.
 */
void eliminatespline (char *a)
{
    char b[MAXL] = "",      /* buffer to hold copy of a */
        *rp = b,            /* read pointer to copy of a */
        *wp = a,            /* write pointer for a */
        last = 0;           /* last char before current */

    if (!a || !*a)          /* a NULL or empty - return */
        return;

    strcpy (b, a);          /* copy a to b */
    while (isspace (*rp))   /* skip leading whitespace */
        rp++;
    last = *rp++;           /* fill last with 1st non-whitespace */

    while (*rp) {           /* loop over remaining chars in b */
        /* last '\n' and current whitespace - advance read pointer */
        if (last == '\n' && isspace(*rp)) {
            rp++;
            continue;
        }   /* last not current or last not space */
        else if (last != *rp || !isspace (last))
            *wp++ = last;   /* write last, advance write pointer */
        last = *rp++;       /* update last, advance read pointer */
    }
    if (!isspace (last))    /* if last not space */
        *wp++ = last;       /* write last, advance write pointer */
    *wp = 0;                /* nul-terminate at write pointer */
}

int main() {

    char a[] = "  hello   world\n  \n\nthis is   my program, cris  ";

    eliminatespline (a);

    printf ("'%s'\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** the line being trimmed has both leading and trailing whitespace as well as embedded blank lines and lines containing only whitespace, e.g.

```
"  hello   world\n  \n\nthis is   my program, cris  "
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/elimspaceline
'hello world
this is my program, cris'
```

(**note:** the `printf` statements wraps the output in *single-quotes* to confirm all leading and trailing whitespace was eliminated.)

If you did want to use `sscanf`, you could essentially do the same thing with `sscanf` (using the `%n` specifier to report characters consumed) and a array of two-characters to treat the next character as a string, and do something like the following:

```
void eliminatespline (char *a)
{
    char b[MAXL] = "",      /* string to hold build w/whitespace removed */
        word[MAXL] = "",    /* string for each word */
        c[2] = "";          /* string made of char after word */
    int n = 0,              /* number of chars consumed by sscanf */
        offset = 0;         /* offset from beginning of a */
    size_t len;             /* length of final string in b */

    /* sscanf each word and char that follows, reporting consumed */
    while (sscanf (a + offset, "%s%c%n", word, &c[0], &n) == 2) {
        strcat (b, word);   /* concatenate word */
        strcat (b, c);      /* concatenate next char */
        offset += n;        /* update offset with n */
    }

    len = strlen (b);       /* get final length of b */
    if (len && isspace(b[len - 1])) /* if last char is whitespace */
        b[len - 1] = 0;     /* remove last char */

    strcpy (a, b);          /* copy b to a */
}
```

Look things over, try both approaches and let me know if you have further questions.